# How do I create a new thread in a WinDBG (live) debugger session?

Tags: windows, windbg

## C Code vs. Debugger Scripts

So, I'm trying to use some *essentially* obfuscated C code (that I cannot easily replicate in a debugger script) to "decode" an object in memory during a WinDBG live debugging session.

My intention is to invoke the function like:

```
.call MyDLL!decode_obj(0x86206922)
```

The catch is that the object pointer I have may be bad (i.e. corrupt, the object may be in some transitional state, etc.) and so I would prefer to create a new thread in which to run this function invocation. If I repurpose one of the existing threads, then I risk hosing my ability to do further investigation on it later.

It seems like it should be possible to create a new thread in the debugging session.
I thought perhaps [CreateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) would do the trick. However, the debugger complains when I attempt to invoke it saying that it's not a function.

```
> .call KERNELBASE!CreateThread(0x0,0x0,0x6329c410,0x0,0x0)
                              ^ Symbol not a function in '.call KERNELBASE!CreateThread(0x0,0x0,0x6329c410,0x0,0x0)'
```

When I try to examine the symbol for it, I learn that the debugger doesn't know its prototype.

```
> x KERNELBASE!CreateThread
76a58930          KERNELBASE!CreateThread (<no parameter info>)
```

The debugger has (public, I presume) symbols loaded for that module:

```
> lm v m KERNELBASE*
76900000 76aa2000   KERNELBASE   (pdb symbols)          
c:\data\src\symcache\wkernelbase.pdb\50E684CA8883458E868AF15C58DF1C2E1\wkernelbase.pdb
```

The [.call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-call--call-function-) documentation mentions the `/s` parameter, in which you can specify a prototype, but I could not find examples of how to specify it and my few attempts were unsuccessful.

#### Can I create a new thread from WinDBG?

This seems like it *ought* to be possible. WinDBG does it when I attach to a running process, and I just need to invoke the correct API, I would think.

#### How do I create a new thread?

Is `CreateThread` the right API to use, or is there a better one?

#### `.call /s` Example(s)?

Are there any examples of how to specify a prototype? If it were a C++ function, would I have to do name mangling? Do I have to resolve all the `typedef`s and CPP macro definitions?

Comment: Do you need [!injectdll](https://lowleveldesign.org/2016/06/22/injectdll-a-windbg-extension-for-dll-injection/)?

Comment: I half expected to be able to do this with native commands/features, but if using an extension is the only way, then it's the only way. )-8